# fgets is returning a blank screen

Tags: c, file, fgets

I am new to C, this is my first project and have been teaching myself. Within my program, one of my functions needs to read a line from a file, and store it in a char array. When I trace the program with gdb the array (line[]) is simply zeros. This leads to my program returning the error "Error: a line in the asset file lacks a ':' separator\n"
Here is my code:

```
//return the line number (0 based) that the cmd is on, -1 if absent
int locateCmd(char cmd[]) {
        int lineIndex = -1;     //-1, because lineIndex is incramented before the posible return
        char cmdTemp[10] = "\0";

        //create a compareable cmd with correct cmd that has its remaining values zeroed out
        char cmdCmp[10] = "\0";
        memset(cmdCmp, 0, sizeof(cmdCmp));
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(cmd); i++) {
                cmdCmp[i] = cmd[i];
        }

        FILE *file = fopen(ASSET_FILE, "r");

        //loop until target line is reached
        while (strcmp(cmdTemp, cmdCmp) != 0)  {
                //check if last line is read
                if (lineIndex == lineCounter(file)-1) {
                        return -1;
                }

                memset(cmdTemp, 0, sizeof(cmdTemp));
                char line[61];
                fgets(line, 61, file);
                //set cmdTemp to the command on current line
                lineIndex++;
                for (int i = 0; line[i] != ':'; i++) {
                        cmdTemp[i] = line[i];

                        //return error if line doesn't contain a ':'
                        if (line[i] = '\n') {
                        printf("Error: a line in the asset file lacks a ':' separator\n");
                        exit(1);
                        }
                }
        }

        return lineIndex;
}
```

Some context, this function is passed a command, and its job is to read a document that appears like this:

```
command:aBunchOfInfoOnTheComand
anotherCommand:aBunchOfInfoOnTheComand
```

and pick out the line that the passed command (cmd[]) is stored on.

The issue is with the fgets on line 24. I have separated the relevant portion of this code out into a smaller test program and it works fine.
The test program that works is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *file = fopen("tutorInfo.txt", "r");
    char line[61];
    fgets(line, 61, file);
    printf("%s\n", line);
}
```

The proper exicution of my test program leads me to believe other code in my function is causing the issue, but i'm not sure what. It may be important to note, the problematic code has the same imports as my sample program. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: your loop will run out of bounds if the line didn't contain `:`. Also you need to make a small test program that shows the problem (not one that works fine)

Comment: In the first code the loop will never exit (the loop condition uses the outer `cmdTemp` which you never update)

Comment: Where is the code for `linecounter(FILE *)`? What is the purpose of passing `FILE *file` into  `locateCmd()` if all you do is opening the file inside the function itself and are not returning the `FILE *`?

Comment: @M.M I would have posted a small test program that didn't work if I had one, however when I attempted to make it the program worked.

Comment: @M.M I see what you mean about cmdTemp, I over looked the fact that they have different pointers even though they have the same name. Is there a good way to reset a string so I don't have to give it a new pointer. A for loop setting all the values to "\0", maybe? Thank you.

Comment: @Stefan Becker I have passed the file so that there is less opportunity for a person modifying the code to for get to change all the occurrences of that file making the program not work, once this problem is resolved I will have it use the passed file.

Comment: @M.M I feel that it is important to mention that the program is stuck in that loop (because there is no ':' in line[]). However, the reason the ':' isn't present is, because line[] is zeroed out, despite me running "fscanf(file, "%s", line);".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As OP didn't provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I have to base my answer on the functional description provided in the question.

I already covered some error and corner cases, but I'm sure I missed some. The approach is also inefficient, as the file is read over and over again, instead of parsing it once and returning a hash/map/directory for easy lookup. In real life code I would use something like [GLib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/) instead of wasting my time trying to re-invent the wheel(s)...

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LINE_BUFFER_LENGTH 200

unsigned int locateCmd(FILE *fh, const char *key, const char **cmd_line) {
  unsigned int found = 0;
  size_t key_length = strlen(key);
  *cmd_line = NULL;

  /* make sure to start read from start of file */
  rewind(fh);

  unsigned int line_no = 0;
  static char buffer[LINE_BUFFER_LENGTH];
  while (!feof(fh) && (found == 0)) {
    // NOTE: EOF condition will be checked on the next iteration
    fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fh);
    size_t length = strlen(buffer);
    line_no++;

    if (buffer[length - 1] != '\n') {
      printf("line %u is too long, aborting!\n", line_no);
      return(0);
    }

    if ((strncmp(key, buffer, key_length) == 0) &&
        (buffer[key_length] == ':')) {
      found              = line_no;
      buffer[length - 1] = '\0'; // strip line ending
      *cmd_line          = &buffer[key_length + 1];
    }
  }

  return(found);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  FILE *fh = fopen("dummy.txt", "r");
  if (!fh) {
    perror("file open");
    return(1);
  }

  int ret = 0;
  while (--argc > 0) {
    const char *cmd;
    const char *key  = *++argv;
    unsigned line_no = locateCmd(fh, key, &cmd);
    if (line_no != 0) {
      printf("key '%s' found on line %u: %s\n", key, line_no, cmd);
      ret = 0;
    } else {
      printf("key '%s' not found!\n", key);
    };
  }

  if (fclose(fh) != 0) {
    perror("file close");
    return(1);
  }

  return(ret);
}
```

Test input `dummy.txt`:

```
command:aBunchOfInfoOnTheComand
anotherCommand:aBunchOfInfoOnTheComand
brokenline

foo:bar
toolong:sadflkjaLKFJASDJFLKASJDFLKSAJ DLFKJ SLDKJFLKASDFASDFKJASKLDJFLKASJDFLKJASDLKFJASLKDFJLKASDJFLKASJDLFKJASDKLFJKLASDJFLKSAJDFLKJASDLKFJKLASDJFLKASJDFKLJASDLKFJLKASDJFLKASJDFLKJSADLKFJASLKDJFLKC
```

Some test runs:

```
$ gcc -Wall -o dummy dummy.c
$ ./dummy command foo bar
key 'command' found on line 1: aBunchOfInfoOnTheComand
key 'foo' found on line 5: bar
line 6 is too long, aborting!
key 'bar' not found!
```

Comment: Thank you so much, the issue was that my lineCounter() function was passed the file so it used the same pointer. This made it so my program was trying to read after the last line. Since I am new to c I didn't know about the feof() function, so I made my own. Once I saw it in your answer I added it into mine and my program now works. Thanks, I really appreciate the time and effort.